# A lot of no-index on products page is bad?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, ecommerce, thin-content

I just started an e-Commerce site and as I am aware of thin page/duplicate page are bad for site. I no-indexing all my product pages which contains only size and colours data for the product ( no unique product description)

I am focusing/expecting/trying to rank well on category pages ( enough unique written contents describing that category ) and article pages.

So now my site will have like 80% of pages as no-index.  So by this I am getting rid of bad effect of thin page/duplicate page.

But is it bad for ranking for having this too many no-index ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so noindexing a lot of pages isn't really directly bad for your site.  However it can have an effect on how Google is crawling your site.

Google only has a set amount 'crawl budget' of time it will spend on your site, if it's busy using this crawl budget on pages that aren't going to be indexed any way, its a waste of crawl budget and may miss crawling important pages.

However if your site isn't very big you don't really need to worry about this.

Another thing to bear in mind is that if you are noindexing 80% of your site, then make sure there is still enough of the site left to index and your not left with a shallow site with thin content. Although it sound like you are covering that with content on your category pages.

Wrapping up, I'd say what you are doing is fine, but I would also try to get content written for your product pages where possible.

Comment: Yeah i do have article get posted on daily basis ( 2-3/day ) . Thanks for crawl budget explanation :)  //nice to know that you are from Bangkok :)